# 'partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener' on kubernetes after kafka restart

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, azure-aks

i have several spring boot apps communicating via kafka running inside a kubernetes cluster. Using the bitnami/kafka helm chart for deploying kafka.

Everything works fine until the kafka broker (i only have a single instance) is restarting. After that i get for producer 'X partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener' ... to fix that i must setup the whole cluster again to make it working means kill all apps, remove kafka and the volumes and put everything back.

Found some stuff regarding "advertised.listeners" but nothing worked yet.
For example that one:
https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/configuring-kafka-on-kubernetes-makes-available-from-an-external-client-with-helm-96e9308ee9f4

The question for me is, why is it working in the beginning and only after crashing it stops ....

Thx
Oliver

Answer (score -1):

> The question for me is, why is it working in the **beginning** and only after crashing it stops ....

When your Kafka broker restarts, it gets a new IP address. You must make sure that the new IP address is reflected in your broker properties i.e. it must be included in the advertised listeners.

You can have a **Kubernetes service** on top of your Kafka deployment and include that in your advertised listeners *as a workaround*.

The other way is to have stateful set so that your broker pod always gets the same IP address. Bring down your broker add the `advertised.listeners` and set it to the broker pod IP and start it.

One rule of thumb, is that your `kafkacat` topic metadata must not return an unreachable address.

Comment: thx for the answer .. i also think that the IP has changed after restart. what i am wondering about is that I have already a service and this service is used by the spring boot apps when i look in the logfile after kafka is failing:

java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: kafka-0.kafka-headless.xy.svc.cluster.local:9092

Comment: @IEE1394 are you able to `telnet kafka-0.kafka-headless.xy.svc.cluster.local 9092`?

Comment: yes i am able to do telnet from a busybox inside the cluster

Comment: @IEE1394 then, you may need to check your advertised.listeners and see if it reflects the same. Did you try getting metadata of the topic using `kafkacat` and see what is the IP there?

Comment: currently i have no kafkacat .. i added it manually to the advertised listeners and give em a try

Comment: Update: looks like setting up a broker id worked out fine?? (using the bitnami helm chart)